# Visual Studio: how to make pressing tab key indent the whole line

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to configure a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio such that tab (or some other key combo) indent the whole line (rather than insert a tab character/spaces at the cursor)?

Trying to determine whether Visual Studio is the [dream editor](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/wiki/My-Dream-Editor)

**EDIT**

I'm an experienced VS user, I know about the standard behavior, just curious whether it can be configured with the interesting tab behavior described in the link.

Comment: It already does this if you select / highlight the line(s).

Comment: DOn't technically need to highlight it. `Home` then `Tab`/`Shift+Tab` does this as well.

Comment: Good pickup @BradChristie. I didn't realise that `Shift+Tab` would work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase indent:

1. Select / highlight line(s) or press <kbd>Home</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>tab</kbd>

Decrease indent:

1. Select / highlight line(s) or press <kbd>Home</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

If you want to add a shortcut to do the same from anywhere in the line without selecting it then you can add a shortcut in Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. There'll be a list of commands including `Edit.IncreaseLineIndent` and `Edit.DecreaseLineIndent`. I couldn't find a good key combination for a shortcut though which wasn't already being used for something else. You can't use just <kbd>tab</kbd> by itself.

Comment: According to OP's link, this would mean if you had "Hello, Wo|rld." (where `|` is the cursor) and you pressed tab, the whole text ("Hello, world.") would indent (and not add a spacer between "Wo" and "rld.")